# Trying to use filter while adding new prop in object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a task and my solution does not work correct.
I have an array of objects "mates", each object consist properties, name and age of each mate(person)
The task is to create a new property "friends", which should consist array of mate names.

Each object in array has prop name, so the prop friends has to consist all object names which don't equal to their own name.

I have made a solution but the array of friends still consist all names, include the name of current object

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS lessons6</title>
</head>
<!--<h1>Lesson 6</h1>-->
<body>

<!--<script src="mainForStudents.js"></script>-->
<script>

    let mates = [
        {name: 'john', age: 44},
        {name: 'bob', age: 33},
        {name: 'sam', age: 2},
    ]

    let updatedMates = mates.map(el => (
        {...el, friends: mates.map(el => el.name).filter(el => el !== el.name)}
        
    ))

    console.log(updatedMates)

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `el` variable name everywhere. When looking for a variable, the last `filter()` method will not have to look for the `el` in the outermost `map()` because an `el` already exists in scope.

You can change your variable names to get this done:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS lessons6</title>
</head>
<!--<h1>Lesson 6</h1>-->
<body>

<!--<script src="mainForStudents.js"></script>-->
<script>

    let mates = [
        {name: 'john', age: 44},
        {name: 'bob', age: 33},
        {name: 'sam', age: 2},
    ]

    let updatedMates = mates.map(el => (
        {...el, friends: mates.map(el1 => el1.name).filter(el2 => el2 !== el.name)}
        
    ))

    console.log(updatedMates)

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Note: It was not **needed** to change the variable name from `el` to `el1` in the inner `.map()`. But I would recommend you to do that, so you can avoid such problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

please see the variable of the inner map and the outer map. I see the same "el".
The correct is :

```js
    let updatedMates = mates.map(el => (
        {...el, friends: mates.map(el => el.name).filter(em => em !== el.name)}
        
    ))
```